# What is Typical rows per value?

Tags: teradata

In tearadata data demographic there are typical rows per value and maximum rows per value.

At the time of PI selection we consider this demographic. Is it the number of duplicate value in a column ?.Please explain .

Answer (score 2):

If the number of rows is almost the same for all values (without any peaks) it's the "row count"/"distinct values". Otherwise you have to consider the topics presented in Teradata's "Database Design" manual:

Chapter 6: The Activity Transaction Modeling Process

Maximum and Typical Column Value Frequencies

http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=131540006